# "We is who the Earth is for?"

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

In the film of The Beasts of the Southern Wild, Hushpuppy the main character of the film says,

> But me and my daddy, we stay right here. “We is who the Earth is for.”

What grammatical structure is she using here?

Comment: Bad grammar. It should be "We are who the Earth is for."

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but it may be possible that she is making a little joke by keeping the form of the question just asked.  The question may have been, "Who *is the Earth for*?"  and instead of saying, "The Earth is for us" she uses the same form and responds with, "***We*** is who the Earth is for."

Comment: @Jim she says : But me and my daddy, we stay right here. We is who the earth is for. I don't think she is making jokes. actually I think what she says does make sense grammatically, however I don't know how

Comment: +1 @Ronan In my experience as a native American English speaker, this sort of formation is very common in urban dialects.

Comment: Ok, she is speaking in a vernacular or dialect where it's common to make this kind of grammar "error".  Note she also says, "Me and my daddy"

Comment: lol I'm surprised I missed the "Me and my daddy" part!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, the correct grammar would be "My daddy and **I** stay right here. The earth is for us" No starting a sentence with "But"; first person nominative singular following another noun for the compound subject of a sentence; plural subject matches plural verb; and no ending a sentence with a preposition,

**BUT** all through the movie, Hushpuppy and many other characters use a stylized regional dialect of English so the rules of grammar become moot. As @Lumberjack said, this "WE IS" formula is a very common mistake for those who speak English as a second language. There could be many reasons for this usage, but it seems the three most likely are:

1. Lack of grammatical instruction
2. Confusion from the interrogative form as @Jim suggested
3. The speaker intuitively interprets "WE" as a collective unit. In their minds this unit is a singular entity, and so they use a singular form of the verb.

The purpose of language is communication, and closed groups tend to form their own rules of usage, grammar and syntax.

Incidentally, Winston Churchill, an excellent communicator, was once challenged by a speechwriter for finishing a sentence with a preposition. He wrote a quick note in response: "This is the kind of pedantic drivel up with which I will not put!"

Comment: Is there any context that we actually can use "we" as a collective unit?

Comment: Not technically in English grammar, but it provides an explanation for the mistake. Once a speaker/listener identifies this mental anomaly, the confusion can be erased.

Comment: The Churchill quote is probably not due to him at all ... http://www.public.wsu.edu/%7Ebrians/errors/churchill.html

Comment: Understood, @GEdgar. The nature of anecdotes as an instructive tool is an interesting topic in its own right. The correct style would have been, "I won't put up with this pedantic drivel!" but then it wouldn't have shown the folly of the speechwriter's pedantic drivel :)

Comment: "No starting a sentence with 'but'" and "no ending a sentence with a preposition" are not actually valid rules of grammar (see https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-a-conjunction).

Comment: @mic “This is the sort of bloody nonsense up with which I will not put!” Welcome to the 21st Century 

Answer (score 4):

The usage is dialectic, and would be incorrect in standard Englishes.

*The Beasts of the Southern Wild* is set in an impoverished and isolated area of southern Louisiana, and filmed in Terrebonne Parish— deep in Acadiana, where many people speak [Cajun English](http://repositori.uji.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10234/76966/-serveis-scp-publ-jfi-xvii-filologia-1.pdf), and some still speak [Cajun French](http://uiswcmsweb.prod.lsu.edu/hss/french/Undergraduate%20Program/Cajun%20French/item49347.html). While inconsistent number agreement itself isn't [distinctively Cajun](https://books.google.com/books?id=yXY0yQnvmmUC&pg=PA4), it is clear that her community is unschooled, and it is unsaid whether Hushpuppy has had any exposure to "proper" grammar.